# How to get button which submitted form

Tags: javascript

I am trying to change the CSS on the submit button for the form *without knowing the ID of the button*. Code looks like:

FORM

```
<form id="sendReminderForm{{ user.id }}" method="post" action="">
    <input type="hidden" name="objectId" value="{{ object.id }}">
    <input type="hidden" name="userId" value="{{ user.id }}">
    <button class="btn btn-warning btn-xs"
            type="submit">
        <span class="fa fa-paper-plane"></span> Remind
    </button>
</form>
```

JS

```
$('form').on('submit', e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    let data = new FormData($(e.target).get(0));

    let submit = ??? // would like to access the button which submitted the form

    $.ajax({
        url: `${siteURL}${itemReminderURL}`,
        type: 'POST',
        enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        headers: {"X-CSRFToken": token},
        data: data,
        success: function (data) {
            submit.classList.remove('btn-warning');
            submit.classList.add('btn-success');
            submit.setAttribute('disabled', true);
        },
```

Comment: strange, you have multiple submit buttons  on the same form ?

Comment: I have multiple forms which are similar which are produced dynamically. Should I make the `<button>` have a dynamic `id` as well?

Comment: and only one submit button per form ?

Comment: Yes. One submit button per form

Comment: Note you don't need to use `$(e.target).get(0)` as it just returns `e.target` .... `let data = new FormData(e.target)`

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: Failed to construct 'FormData': parameter 1 is not of type 'HTMLFormElement'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are already using jQuery it's simpler to use it for what you are needing to do as you can chain the methods into a one liner

```js
$('form').submit(e=>{
    e.preventDefault();
    const $btn = $(e.target).find('button:submit')
     
   // in ajax success
   $btn.toggleClass('btn-warning btn-success').prop('disabled', true)
})
```

```css
.btn-warning{background:yellow}
.btn-success{background:palegreen}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="sendReminderForm{{ user.id }}" method="post" action="">
    <input type="hidden" name="objectId" value="{{ object.id }}">
    <input type="hidden" name="userId" value="{{ user.id }}">
    <button class="btn btn-warning btn-xs"
            type="submit">
        <span class="fa fa-paper-plane"></span> Remind
    </button>
</form>
```

Comment: Great answer! I tried using find but my syntax was wrong. This allows me to get the button which submitted the form *without* knowing the ID

Answer (score 1):

this is simply

```
let submitButoon = e.target.querySelector('button[type="submit"]') 
submitButoon.disabled = true
```

Answer (score 0):

`e.target` will be the `form` element. Therefore, you can use a `getElementById` to get the button.

Change

```
<button class="btn btn-warning btn-xs"
            type="submit">
...
let submit = ???
...
```

to

```
...
<button class="btn btn-warning btn-xs"
            type="submit" id="submit">
...
let submit = e.target.getElementById('submit');
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I might be missing something but can't you add a classname to the button and target it via css selector? Something like:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <style>
      .button-style {
        background: red;
        font-size: 24px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form id="sendReminderForm{{ user.id }}" method="post" action="">
      <button class="button-style" type="submit">Remind</button>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```